# How to analyze binary categorical vs ordinal data?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data, sas, ordered-logit

**Context:** I have a dataset in which I am analyzing whether a patient having 1 disease (binary) influences the number of other diseases the patient has (ordinal; range = 0-7), which is the outcome variable.

**Questions:**

1. Is the number of other diseases the patient has in fact ordinal?
2. What regression method would I use to analyze this data where the outcome variable is ordinal?
3. My other explanatory variables include age, race, gender, etc. I am using SAS, so could I use `PROC LOGISTIC` or `PROC GLM`?
4. Also, what method would I use to test the simple correlation between the two? Is there something similar to the chi-square for a 2 by 8 table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The number of diseases that the patient has would be *interval* as opposed to *ordinal* in most usual representations- certainly, if the number represents a count of the individual diseases (among `n`, where it appears in this case `n = 7`), this would be more properly characterized as *interval* data.
2. The general pattern of regressing to levels of response is called *ordinal regression*- this is not to say that this is the only method that would be applicable to this question. Many multiclass regression methods could be applicable as well, [some are discussed in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/multinomial-logistic-regression-vs-one-vs-rest-binary-logistic-regression).
3. `Proc Logistic` is capable of ordinal regression using the `oddsratio` option, as discussed in [this SAS documentation example](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect061.htm).
4. As it happens, a Chi-Squared measure is reported in the output of `Proc Logistic` using the method described in the example in *3*.