# Is one-vs-all logit or multionomial logit regression more accurate?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, econometrics, multinomial-distribution, logit

What is advice of when to use one-vs-all logit or multinomial logit regressions? Most importantly, which one has a higher prediction power? Can one test hypothesis and estimate confidence intervals in one-vs-all approach?

I came from economics and I have just recently started to dive into Machine Learning. I noticed that they use different approaches to estimate discrete choice models. However, I could not find any paper or website where somebody would compare those two approaches. I found this, but it does not answer the question of prediction power: [Multinomial logistic regression vs one-vs-rest binary logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/multinomial-logistic-regression-vs-one-vs-rest-binary-logistic-regression#)

Comment: We know they are two different models, why should we compare the prediction power?

Comment: Because we still want to predict the same thing: what option will be chosen. Therefore, you could compare, for example, how many right predictions were made on a new set of data using those two approaches.

Comment: To me, they are **not** predicting the same thing. It's just Apple and Orange.