# Comparing three groups on one categorical dependent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, multiple-comparisons

I want to compare three groups (three different ethnic groups) on one dependent variable that is categorical (3 categories). What test do I use?

I am using SPSS, so some advice on how to do it would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is your dependent variable? I don't assume it's ethnicity membership...

Comment: The dependent variable is voting behavior with three possible categorical outcomes. Ethnicity membership is the variable used to create the groups from the sample.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are interested in is the relationship between a single categorical IV and a single categorical DV, then a contingency table analysis is appropriate. You will find a lot of info online and in the SPSS help. [This may be a good place to start.](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter16.pdf)

If you have more IVs, and possibly also interactions, things get a little more complicated.

Your response is categorical. Specifically, it is *multinomial*, i.e., you have more than two possible outcomes. (With just two outcomes, you could use a logistic regression. With three outcomes, that is not a straightforward possibility.) The standard approach would be a multinomial logistic model, with your groups and other IVs as predictors, potentially modeling interactions. This earlier question might be helpful (and also contains SPSS info): [Multinomial logistic regression vs one-vs-rest binary logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/52104/1352)