# Best way to perform logistic regression for two dependent variables simultaneously

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis

**Explanation:**

Lets say we have a dataset, df with '*n*' columns/variables. Two of '*n*' variables are named as Case 1 and Case 2. Case 1 and Case 2 are categorical variables with value levels "Low" and "High".

**Logistic regression:**

Dependent variable: Case 1 and Case 2

Independent variable: Remaining (*n-2*) columns

Objective: I want to predict the probability of getting a low and high level based on variable "Case 1" and "Case 2".

Question: What are alternatives to multivariate logistic regression or what is the best way to perform this kind of multivariate logistic regression?

[image]

Comment: You can re-code the two levels of each of Case 1 and Case 2 as 4 levels of one variable (all combinations of the 2 levels). Each row will be 1 of the 4 levels, so this is a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: To follow up that comment by @Sycorax, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52104.

Comment: You can use ordinal logistic regression if you have ordered categories

Comment: @Lelouch Good point--but there is no inherent order when multiple categories are present.