# Coefficients of dummy variables in a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interpretation

I wanted to know what is the difference between running a multinomial logit regression and a logit regression on a model in which the dependent variable is a dummy with just two levels.

My database looks like this

```
Firm     Event      Year       Info       Dummy14      Dummy15     Dummy16
1        0          2014        x           1             0           0
1        0          2015        x           0             1           0
1        1          2016        x           0             0           1
2        0          2014        x           1             0           0
2        1          2015        x           0             1           0
3        0          2014        x           1             0           0
3        0          2015        x           0             1           0
3        0          2016        x           0             0           1
4        1          2014        x           1             0           0
```

Basically, I have analysed some firms for the years 2014-2016, eliminating them if an event happens.
I have also added some dummies (equal to 1 if we are in a specific year) to implement a year fixed effects model.

The logistic regression is the following:

```
Event ~ Info + Dummy14 + Dummy15 + Dummy16
```

(I want to check if the info in the year previous to the event are different from the other years)

I want to understand the coefficients of the dummies.
If Dummy16 is equal to +20, does it mean that the event is more likely to happen in 2016? Is it a percentage?
I don't understand the fact that it can be equal to a high number, since both the dependent variable and the dummies can only be equal to 0 and 1.

Side note: I don't know if it is relevant, but I invented the coefficient of Dummy16, and, maybe, in this simplified case it can't be equal to +20.
So, for the sake of clarity, I will specify that, in my actual database, I have 9 dummies for the years from 2013 to 2021 and the actual coefficients are:
Dummy13 = +13
Dummy14 = +23
Dummy15 = +13
Dummy16 = +6
Dummy17 = +0.6
Dummy18 = -25.4
Dummy19 = -51
Dummy20 = -65.8
Dummy21 = -23

Comment: You sound like in a decision between a multinomial and a binary logistic regression, right? Then maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/52104/3277) and similar threads are helpful.

Comment: No, I just would like to understand how to interpret the coefficients, I am not in a decision between multinomial and binary logistic regression. What do the coefficients of the dummy mean?

Comment: How to interpret coefficients of dummy predictors? This topic has been covered million of time. One general introduction of contrast variables such as dummy and other types is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/3277), for example.

Comment: Ok but dummy variables in a logit regression. I know that, for example, if I have a regression where the dependent variable is the death rate, and I have dummies indicating the US states, the coefficient of the dummies will indicate how the death rate varies with respect to the state taken as base level. I do not understand however how it works on the logit regression, and how the coefficient can be higher than 1

Comment: Logistic regression is a linear regression via logit link function. Whereas in linear regr. we interpret b (a regr. coef), in logistic regr. we interpret exp(b).

Comment: Please do not reask the Q, but edit the original version!