# Assessing differences in effect size of an independent variable: multinomial logistic regression or one-vs-rest binary logistic regression

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, effect-size, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

My question pertains to [this Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/multinomial-logistic-regression-vs-one-vs-rest-binary-logistic-regression), but I specifically aim to compare the effect size of an independent variable between categories of the dependent variable.

In practice, I have a non-ordinal dependent variable with four categories representing cultural consumption clusters. I have three independent predictors: Gender (binary), Age (continuous), and Social Origin (categorized into three groups). I want to assess whether the effect of social origin on the probability of belonging to one cluster differs for each cluster.

Should I use multinomial logistic regression or one-vs-rest binary logistic regression for each category of the dependent variable? Or perhaps there's another model I'm not aware of?